# Combining Powershell Commands in a Foreach Loop

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to powershell, and am wondering why this isn't working.  Basically, I have a foreach loop that checks if IIS is running and reports the OS version if so and writes this out to a file.  However, it's not reporting correctly.  It seems like it gets the values for the first item (IIS state and OS) and then populates it through the other items in my loop.

```
#Get List of Servers to Scan
$servers = (Get-Content e:\servers.txt)

#Determine if IIS is Running
foreach($server in $servers){
$iis = get-wmiobject Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "name='IISADMIN'";

if($iis.State -eq "Running")
{$OSVer= [environment]::OSVersion.Version}

Write-Host "$server,$IISRun,$OSVer" | Out-File -FilePath "E:\results.txt"
}
```

The Results:

```
 Server1,true,5.2.3790.131072     <---- Correct
 Server2,true,5.2.3790.131072     <---- Correct 
 Server3,true,5.2.3790.131072     <---- Wrong OS reported (windows 2008)
 Server4,true,5.2.3790.131072     <---- Wrong OS reported (windows 2008)
 Server5,true,5.2.3790.131072     <---- IIS isn't installed here at all
 Server6,true,5.2.3790.131072     <---- IIS isn't installed here at all
```

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: `[environment]::OSVersion.Version` retrieves the local OS version of the system where you are running the PS script.

Comment: And you aren't putting the `write-host` command in the "is IIS running" block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[environment]::OSVersion.Version` gets you your local OS version. Use `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server` instead to get target computer's OS information, e.g.:

```
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $iis = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "name='IISADMIN'"
    $os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server

    $iisRunning = $iis.State -eq "Running"
    $osVersion = $os.Version

    Write-Host "$server, $iisRunning, $osVersion"
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service` over `Get-Service`?